# insert data if null

Tags: sql, oracle11g

anyone please help me i have **procedure** in **oracle** when the procedure is run table **Rekon** its get data from another table to create data, but the problem is when the data is null(empty) in another table in Table **Rekon** it's null but i want still have data in my **Rekon** table, example for template:

```
NO_ACC|ttrx|Amount    
1111  |USD |2200
      |SGD |5410
      |total|7610
```

but when the data in another table **is null** in where clause substr(NARATION,1,3)='SGD'
the table its like:

```
NO_ACC|ttrx|Amount    
1111  |USD |2200
      |total|2200
```

it's my query:

```
insert into datamart.rekon_801_ugm_sm
        select to_char(no_acc) no_acc, 'USD' ttrx, sum(amount) amount from (select 
            * from rekon_801_ugm where no_acc = 1111 and substr(narasi,9,4)='1112' 
            or substr(narasi,37,4)='1112') group by no_acc 
            union all
        select to_char(no_acc) no_acc, 'SGD' as ttrx, sum(amount) amount from (select 
            * from rekon_801_ugm where no_acc = 8010000487 and substr(narasi,9,2)='88' 
            or substr(narasi,37,2)='88') group by no_acc
            union all
        select ' ' as no_acc, 'TOTAL TRANSAKSI H2H' as ttrx, sum(amount) amount from (select 
            * from rekon_801_ugm where no_acc = 1111 and debet_kredit = 'K') group by no_acc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using acc_no with a constant condition in all sub queries
if you want to have null values you must replace this condition with something like

(acc_no=8010000487 or acc_no is null)